# Windows phone music player

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a music player using X N A in windows phone.
Here I am using a slider to automatic synchronizing of songs.
Problem is how can i seek song in slider .I am also using timer.

```
 MediaPlayer.PlayPosition=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(slider1.Value);
```

I have tried mediaPlayer.PlayPosition propety in slider mouse left button event but it is saying play position property is read only.So
please help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems practically impossible to do..

Here's the UserVoice request, asking just this.
http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2411252-mediaplayer-playposition-should-be-able-to-be-set

There are some other tricks to accomplish this, as explained in this question. (Though it would be an overkill by the look of it.)

> [XNA MediaPlayer fastforward/rewind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518602/xna-mediaplayer-fastforward-rewind)